# Canvas Width and Height in Pixels

Tags: c#, canvas, windows-8, winrt-xaml

I'm trying to get the Width and Height of a `Canvas` in Pixels.

How can I do that?

Comment: In which language? (JavaScript?)

Comment: No, I'm using C#/XAML

Answer (score 0):

[ActualHeight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.actualheight.aspx) & [ActualWidth](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.actualwidth.aspx). Listen to [SizeChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.sizechanged.aspx) to catch changes.

Comment: @MBZ you would need to post more information to help diagnose

Comment: @MBZ, ActionX properties listen to `SizeChanged` events which means they are populated either after the document is loaded (using the Loaded event for initial value) or after SizeChanged is raised. My guess is that you are reading zero because you are reading too early.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the loaded event to get the actual width and `ActualHeight` of the `Canvas`.

```
private void Canvas_Loaded_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var height = cnvMain.ActualHeight;
        var width = cnvMain.ActualWidth;
    }
```

`ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight` will give you the  Width and Height of a `Canvas` in Pixels but it will be zero until and unless the canvas is loaded/ rendered on the screen.